# Treat try and except the same

Tags: python, sockets

I'm writing something that checks if a port is open, but modifying it to my use.

I set timeout for the check and if timeout reaches it raises `socket.timeout` exception, but I want a code block inside the `try` to also be invoked on `socket.timeout`:

```
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(5)
    result = sock.connect_ex((check_server_ip, check_port))
    if result == 0:
        # act on open port
    else:
        # act on closed port
    sock.close()
except socket.timeout:
    # act on closed port
```

The code block I have on `# act on closed port` is long. I can create a function that has the code and call it on the `else` statement and `socket.timeout` exception, but I bet python has something more clever.

What can achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for `finally:`?

Comment: @tripleee no because `if result == 0` I don't want it to be invoked, and `finally` is invoked all the time.

Comment: `whether = True; try: things; if result == 0: whether = False; etc; finally: if whether:` do things with closed socket?

Comment: @tripleee cool that could work

Comment: If you're gonna go with that, change the variable name. `whether` is a very bad name.

Comment: Why don't you use `connect()` rather than `connect_ex()`? The `if`/`else` would drop out, the _act on open port_ would only be in the `try` and the _act on closed port_ only in the `except` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need something clever or magical here. I looked at your code, then entered `python -c "import this"` in my terminal and saw this among the lines:

> Flat is better than nested.

So, you don't need to create, set timeout and close a socket in the `try ... except timeout` - nothing throws timeout there:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(5)

try:
    result = sock.connect_ex((check_server_ip, check_port))
    socket_connected = result == 0
except socket.timeout:
    socket_connected = False

if socket_connected:
    do_connected_stuff()
else:
    do_disconnected_stuff()

sock.close()
```

However, the correctness of this code really depends on if `do_connected_stuff()` can throw `socket.timeout` and if `do_disconnected_stuff()` is a meaningful action in this case. If yes to all questions, then you've already got a pretty much optimal structure - at least without the full view of your system.